# In Magento 2.4 Cart page showing "Estimate Shipping and Tax"

Tags: magento2.4, magento-cloud

I am doing fresh setup on Magento Cloud server and facing below issue.

**Issue:** Page break with error while redirecting to **Cart** page.

> [image: Error shown on Browser]

**Steps followed :**

- Add product into Cart
- Click on "Shopping Cart" from message when added to cart or redirect from cart icon
- Redirect to the cart "/checkout/cart/" landed with attached error.

**Note**:  I have multi-store setup for different regions and this error occurs when I work with different store websites , like **au/checkout/cart/** or **us/checkout/cart/** . The default store works well without any error.

**Environment Details**:

- Magento Cloud Server
- Magento 2.4

When I check the logs, I found below errors

```
[2020-09-01 06:35:06] report.ERROR: Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway). [] []
```

> [2020-09-01 06:35:06] report.ERROR:
> Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken
> needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway). [] [] [2020-09-01 06:35:06]
> report.ERROR: Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or
> accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway). [] []
> [2020-09-01 06:35:06] report.ERROR:
> Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken
> needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway). [] [] [2020-09-01 06:35:06]
> report.ERROR: Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or
> accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway). [] []
> [2020-09-01 06:35:06] report.CRITICAL: TypeError: explode() expects
> parameter 2 to be string, null given in
> /app/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Model/Lpm/Config.php:125
> Stack trace:
> #0 /app/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Model/Lpm/Config.php(125): explode(',', NULL)
> #1 /app/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Model/Lpm/Ui/ConfigProvider.php(39):
> PayPal\Braintree\Model\Lpm\Config->getAllowedMethods()
> #2 /app/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(39):
> PayPal\Braintree\Model\Lpm\Ui\ConfigProvider->getConfig()
> #3 /app/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(84): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
> #4 /app/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(120): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getCheckoutConfig()
> #5 /app/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml(36):
> Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getSerializedCheckoutConfig()
> #6 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/app/vendor/mag...')
> #7 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(273): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping),
> '/app/vendor/mag...', Array)
> #8 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(303): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/app/vendor/mag...')
> #9 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1111): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
> #10 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1115):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()
> #11 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(675): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
> #12 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(566): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
> #13 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.cart.s...')
> #14 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
> #15 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...',
> false)
> #16 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('cart.summary', false)
> #17 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cart.summary')
> #18 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cart.summary', false)
> #19 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('checkout.cart.c...',
> false)
> #20 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.c...')
> #21 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.c...',
> false)
> #22 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('checkout.cart.i...',
> false)
> #23 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.i...')
> #24 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(522): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.i...',
> true)
> #25 /app/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml(16):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('with-items')
> #26 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/app/vendor/mag...')
> #27 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(273): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart),
> '/app/vendor/mag...', Array)
> #28 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(303): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/app/vendor/mag...')
> #29 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1111):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
> #30 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1115):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()
> #31 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(675): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
> #32 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(566): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
> #33 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.cart')
> #34 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart')
> #35 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart', false)
> #36 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
> #37 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
> #38 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
> #39 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
> #40 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
> #41 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
> #42 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
> #43 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
> #44 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
> #45 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
> #46 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
> #47 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
> #48 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
> #49 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
> #50 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(594): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
> #51 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
> #52 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(497): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
> #53 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(963): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
> #54 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
> #55 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput',
> Array)
> #56 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
> #57 /app/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(65):
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput',
> Array, Array)
> #58 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
> #59 /app/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #60 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #61 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult',
> Array)
> #62 /app/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #63 /app/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26):
> Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult',
> Array, Array)
> #64 /app/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(120): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #65 /app/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
> #66 /app/pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
> #67 {main} [] []

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you get any solution. I am also getting the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.. will update you if i'll find it.

Comment: @Ups did you find the issue?

Comment: Answer by @Sergey Uskov above fixed it for me. A null entry had sneaked into core_config_data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @duntuk and @Will Wright for giving efforts to solve this issue. much appreciated.

This issue was due to Braintree modules in Magento 2.4.0 and the following solutions I found for this issue.

- please check configuration, Magento 2.4.0 release notes and official vendor website to keep Braintree module:

  - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/braintree.html
  - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-commerce.html
  - https://www.braintreepayments.com/
  - https://help.braintreepayments.com/
- **Disable them (PayPal_Braintree, PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl) if not needed:**
  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html

> **Please Note:**
> If you want to disable the module , you cannot make changes directly to the files in the cloud environment as it is read-only.
>
> You must follow the standard deployment workflow to make any changes:
>
> 1. Make any changes in your local environment
>
>    - `bin/magento module:disable PayPal_Braintree PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl`
>      ***OR***
>    - You can set the ***PayPal_Braintree*** and ***PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl*** module status to '**0**'
>      in ***app/etc/config.php*** using the branch you want to update.
> 2. Push/commit the changes to the desired environment, then redeploy
>
> Please refer to the following for more details:
>
> - https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/architecture/starter-develop-deploy-workflow.html
> - https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html#upgrade-extensions

I choose the 2nd option to disable these modules as I don't need them and that fixed my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I faced with this issue also. But in my case disabling of modules is not a solution because we use it for paypal.

But I found what causing this error - "`payment/braintree_local_payment/allowed methods`" row in "`core_config_data`" with value=`NULL`.

It appeared when I saved settings for other payment method in website scope.

Removing of this row fixed the issue.

Issue didn't appeared again after this when I saved payments again.

Comment: Same problem here. Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Small typo: missing underscore in "allowed_methods"

Answer (score 2):

```
bin/magento module:disable PayPal_Braintree PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl
```

Also if you only have a single site setup "default" you should go into the database "core_config_data" and remove all scope="website" or just the ones relating to "%braintree%"

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions quite worked for me.

I had to patch the following function to make it more defensive. This is obviously not ideal as it is a core Magento 2 module.

Path to file:
/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Model/Lpm/Config.php:119

```
public function getAllowedMethods(): array
{
    $this->allowedMethods = [];
    $allowedMethods = [];
    if ($this->getValue(self::KEY_ALLOWED_METHODS,$this->storeConfigResolver->getStoreId()))
    {
        $allowedMethods = explode(',',$this->getValue(self::KEY_ALLOWED_METHODS,$this->storeConfigResolver->getStoreId()));
    }
    foreach ($allowedMethods as $allowedMethod) {
        $this->allowedMethods[] = [
            'method' => $allowedMethod,
            'label' => constant('self::LABEL_'.strtoupper($allowedMethod)),
            'countries' => constant('self::COUNTRIES_'.strtoupper($allowedMethod))
        ];
    }
    return $this->allowedMethods;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.1 has the following populated by default, I suspect that the merchant ID field you have is empty, it was for me, if you put in the value testmode it then works correctly.

[image]